# gcc compilation flag

Tags: gcc

hi everybody out there 
can any on\e tell me what is -pedantic flag in gcc ? 
like we use at command line  gcc -pedantic filename.c.
i don't know why we use -pedantic flag ?
please explain with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pedantic flag causes the compiler to do extra error checking, which makes it flag problems in your code that it might otherwise ignore, and it also turns off some GCC extensions. Using it is A Good Thing.

Answer (score 8):

```
-Wall
```

Gcc will display all the "GNU" warnings

```
-ansi
```

Gcc will display all the ANSI diagnostics that GNU agree with

```
-pedantic
```

Gcc will display more ANSI diagnostics which GNU doesn't necessarily agree with.